# Is asserting mocked object and method necessary in Unit Test(JUnit 5)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, tdd, junit5

I'm still a basic learner for Unit Test.

I'm trying to mock my class's method without directly calling it(since it is dependent on 3rd party library) and I wrote a test method like below.

(The 3rd party library which I mentioned is not `MapStruct`, it is `ModelObject.class` and it has very complicated parameters for the constructor and is only available to initialize in library level)

The `ProjectMapper` class's `toDto` method is a simple object mapping method(with `MapStruct` library).

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Should convert Project ModelObject to Project DTO successfully.")
void testProjectModelObjectToDtoSucess() {
    // Given 
    ModelObject mockModelObject = mock(ModelObject.class); // <-- Mocking "ModelObject.class" 

    ProjectDto expected = new ProjectDto("PPJT-00000001", "Test Project 01"); // <-- Initializing expected return object.

    when(mockProjectMapper.toDto(mockModelObject)).thenReturn(expected); // <-- Mocking cut(class under test)'s method. 

    // When 
    ProjectDto actual = mockProjectMapper.toDto(mockModelObject); // <-- Calling mocked method. 

    // Then 
    assertEquals(actual.getId(), expected.getId(), "The converted DTO's ID should equal to expected DTO's ID.");
    assertEquals(actual.getName(), expected.getName(), "The converted DTO's name should equal to expected DTO's name.");
}
```

What I want to know is if I already assume `mockProjectMapper.toDto()` will return exactly equaled `expected` object, why would I need to assert with the `actual`(returned) object?

I learned that Unit Test should test any codes which can be breakable.

I doubt what's the benefit of this way of the test and if it's inappropriate, what's the correct way to test this method with mocking?

I referenced this test method from [this example code](https://github.com/geekcap-pluralsight/productservice/blob/master/src/test/java/com/globomantics/productservice/service/ProductServiceTest.java#L83-L94).

@refael-sheinker Here's the source code of the `ProjectMapper` class which is `MapStruct`'s interface class.

```java
@Mapper
public interface ProjectMapper {
    ProjectMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ProjectMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "projectId")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "projectName")
    ProjectDto toDto(ModelObject modelObject);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code of the `ProjectMapper` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mocked your object under test and stubbed method under test - and you correctly concuded that such a test brings no benefit.

You are checking that you can stub a method, not your production code.

The main problem is your assumption that you need to mock every 3rd party class. This is wrong way of thinking - you should try to mock collaborators of your class (especially ones that cause side-effects unwanted in the test environment), but not the classes which are critical part of implementation of your class. The line might be sometimes blurry, but in this concrete example I strongly recommend NOT mocking the mapper:

- your 3rd party class is driven by annotations
- the annotations must correspond to your DTOs fields
- the field names in annotations are Strings, their presence is DTOs is not enforced by compiler
- all mapping is done in the memory

Creating a test that exercises production code gives you confidence that:

- field names are correct
- corresponding mapped fields have correct types (for example, you are not mapping int to boolean)

The linked test of the service is somewhat different: it tests a Spring service which calls the repository. The repository presumably represents some DB, which interacts with the outside world - it is a good candidate for a mock. To my eyes the service method only forwards the call to the repository - which is a trivial behaviour - so the test is trivial, but this setup will scale for more complicated service methods.

**Update**

Mocking source class for MapStruct.

If `ModelObject` is complicated to create, consider using mocks for some of its constructor parameters.

```java
var pN = mock(ParamN.class);
// possibly stub some interactions with pN
var modelObject = new ModelObject(10, 20, pN);
```

Alternatively, you could even mock entire ModelObect and stub its getters:

```java
var mockModelObject = mock(ModelObject.class); 
when(mockModelObject.getId()).thenReturn(10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. However, the 3rd party library which I mentioned is not `MapStruct` and it is the `ModelObject.class`. Sorry if my question was confusing. I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: @wonsuc You seem to be caring about only 2 fields in `ModelObject` Is it possible to mock the constructor parameters of `ModelObject`?

Comment: It has actually more fields and little more complicated. I wrote code here simply for easy understanding to people who read this question.

Comment: Thank you for an updated answer, so your point is that if I mock `ProjectMapper.toDto()` method, my original test code has no benefits right?

Comment: Yes, if you intend to test `ProjectMapper.toDto` and you stub precisely this method, there is no benefit in the test.